# There must be a way to procedurally generate this array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on making an array that is my data structure for my D3 element.

I'm about to sit down and do this:

```js
var arcData = [{
  domain: data[0].name,
  count: data[0].count,
  color: data[0].color,
  innerRadius: 0,
  outerRadius: h / 1.75,
  startAngle: (Math.PI * -20) / 180,
  endAngle: (Math.PI * 20) / 180,
}, {
  domain: data[1].name,
  count: data[1].count,
  color: data[1].color,
  innerRadius: 0,
  outerRadius: Math.sqrt((firstArea * (data[1].count / data[0].count)) / angle / Math.PI),
  startAngle: (Math.PI * 20) / 180,
  endAngle: (Math.PI * 60) / 180,
}, ..., {
  domain: data[10].name,
  count: data[10].count,
  color: data[10].color,
  innerRadius: 0,
  outerRadius: Math.sqrt((firstArea * (data[10].count / data[0].count)) / angle / Math.PI),
  startAngle: (Math.PI * 20) / 180,
  endAngle: (Math.PI * 60) / 180,
}]
```

Manually writing this out 10 times.

I've a few more pieces to do, but essentially I want to +1 the index each time I write this up to 10, so my array is complete. I am feeling that the manual way is just a way of bumping up my lines for no reason. Surely there is a more pragmatic way to write this out?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like something [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) could help with, can you share your `data` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arcData = [{
  {
  domain: data[0].name,
  count: data[0].count,
  color: data[0].color,
  innerRadius: 0,
  outerRadius: h / 1.75,
  startAngle: (Math.PI * -20) / 180,
  endAngle: (Math.PI * 20) / 180,
},
}];
for(i= 1; i< data.length; i++) {
  var t = {
  domain: data[i].name,
  count: data[i].count,
  color: data[i].color,
  innerRadius: 0,
  outerRadius: Math.sqrt((firstArea * (data[i].count / data[0].count))/ angle / Math.PI),
  startAngle: (Math.PI * 20) / 180,
  endAngle: (Math.PI * 60) / 180,
  }
  arcData.push(t);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this do this infintely? I only need 10

Comment: replace i<data.length to i<10

Answer (score 0):

You may use functional approach and map it

```js
data.map((it, index) => ({
  domain: it.name,
  count: it.count,
  color: t.color,
  innerRadius: 0,
  outerRadius: h / 1.75,
  startAngle: (Math.PI * -20) / 180,
  endAngle: (Math.PI * 20) / 180
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
const data = [...] //your array of 10 items

const arcData = Array(data.length).fill(null).map((u, i) => {
return {domain: data[i].name,
  count: data[i].count,
  color: data[i].color,
  innerRadius: 0,
  outerRadius: h / 1.75,
  startAngle: (Math.PI * -20) / 180,
  endAngle: (Math.PI * 20) / 180,}

})
```

Comment: `map()` returns a new array anyway, so just `data.map((u,i)...`, or `data.slice(0, 10).map(...` if the OP only wants a partial of the data array.